# How to make a relationship between tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, go, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, go-gorm

I want to have some relation between my tables in MySQL. I use GORM ORM and go. I have 3 table with this name: singertbl, covertbl, singerscovertbl. 
my tables have id with autoincrement value. 
in singertbl and covertbl, I have this fields: ID and {some another field}.
and in singerscovertbl I have this fields: ID, singer_id, cover_id.
there is a relation between {ID.singertbl -> singer_id.singerscovertbl} and 
{ID.covertbl -> cover_id.singerscovertbl} when I want to apply this relation as a foreign key in MySQL workbench with this SQL query:

```
    ALTER TABLE `mskm`.`albumscovers` 
ADD INDEX `ID_idx` (`album_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
ADD INDEX `ID_idx1` (`cover_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `mskm`.`albumscovers` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `ID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`)
  REFERENCES `mskm`.`albumstbls` (`ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

I get this error:

```
 Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `mskm`.`albumscovers` 
ADD INDEX `ID_idx` (`album_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
ADD INDEX `ID_idx1` (`cover_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `mskm`.`albumscovers` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `ID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`)
  REFERENCES `mskm`.`albumstbls` (`ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
ADD INDEX `ID_idx1` (`cover_id` ASC) VISIBLE' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `mskm`.`albumscovers` 
ADD INDEX `ID_idx` (`album_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
ADD INDEX `ID_idx1` (`cover_id` ASC) VISIBLE
```

how I can make this relationship between this tables?!

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? Invisible indexes come in on version 8 'By default, all indexes are visible' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.36-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: I don't think invisible indexes are available to you. Mysqlworkbench is likely out of step with your version if mariadb - follow the link I attached in my previous comment.

Comment: MariaDB doesn't seem to support invisible indexes: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-index/. Invisible *columns* are [supported since 10.3.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/invisible-columns/).

Comment: Please clarify posts via edits, not comments.